# Adding custom data list to alsfresco share

Tags: repository, share, alfresco, datalist

i am a newbie in Alfresco. I have created custom datalist models, context model and also configured the share config xml file and everything is working well. How ever the datalist is not showing when i log in alfresco. What should i do then.

Comment: What do you mean by "the dalalist is not showing" ? Anyway, did you follow this tutorial : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-data-lists.html. The sample code is accessible at the end, it might help you to find what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create one of your custom datalists on the page :
http://"myhostandport"/share/page/site/"mysite"/data-lists

Does it show up there?

If not:

-Did you declare your datalist content model as a bean with  parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap"?

-Does your content model type extend dl:dataListItem

-You can find all the datalists of your type with this kind of query:       `@dl\:dataListItemType:'myprefix\:mydatalisttype'`

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
 
<beans>
 
    <!-- Registration of new models -->  
<bean id="extension.plp.dictionaryBootstrap" parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
        <property name="models">
            <list>
                <value>alfresco/extension/plpDatalistModel.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
 
</beans>

Comment: Yes i created the datalist, but when i am in javascript if I try to query using the prefix plp, it will produce an error message to say datalist is not found. How do I create a datalist that can be associated with the prefix i created e.g "plp": and the query is as follows: -

Comment: I have created 2 datalist files, which are named plpDatalistModel.xml and plpDatalist-model-context.xml. i also adited the share config file in web-extension together with properties file in the messages folder and i have also restarted alfresco.

Comment: var propName = "fileNumber";
  var propValue = caseNumber;
  var query = "TYPE:\"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/datalist/1.0}dataListItem\" +@plp\\:" + propName + ":" + propValue;
  var lookup = search.luceneSearch(query); the @plp cant link my code to the datalist, thats my challenge. I edited the

Comment: Try query: @dl:dataListItemType:'plp:mydatalisttype' where mydatalisttype is your type that extends dl:dataListItem

Comment: i have tried to no avail. i am not sure were am going wrong, however i already have some custom datalist that exists in my datalist but my data list i have created is not showing. should i use amps to load the new one if so how can i do it